# How to run a command in Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to feed the file name dynamically to a command through windows batch script. Here's my code,

```
@echo off
set /p path="Enter the project path: "
for /R "%path%" %%I in (*.java) do (java -classpath MyCheckStyle.jar;checkstyle-5.6-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c custom_check.xml %%I)
pause
```

Basically, I want to get all the .java files from any given directory and feed those java files to another command which will run for each file. In place of `%%I` I am trying to provide the java file dynamically. But it says java command not recognized.

If I use `java -classpath MyCheckStyle.jar;checkstyle-5.6-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c custom_check.xml path/filename.java` alone in a batch  file. It works fine.

I have tried the following also,

```
@echo off

set i=-1
set /p path="Enter the project path: "

for /R "%path%" %%I in (*.java) do (
 set /a i=!i!+1
 set filenames[!i!]=%%I
)
set lastindex=!i!

for /L %%f in (0,1,!lastindex!) do ( 
  java -classpath MyCheckStyle.jar;checkstyle-5.6-all.jar com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main -c custom_check.xml !names[%%f]!
)
pause
```

But again it says java command not recognized.

What am doing wrong here? Why I can not pass the .java file names dynamically?

Comment: It doesn't find java.exe in your PATH.

Comment: But if I run the command alone in a batch script it works fine. I can able to run the command in command prompt also. So there is no problem with java PATH I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your named your variable with project path "path", and it's bad, because as soon as you do

```
set /p path="Enter the project path: "
```

you overwrite the system "path" and then Windows cannot find your "java.exe".
Rename it to project_path:

```
set /p project_path="Enter the project path: "
for /R "%project_path%" %%I in .......
```